# how to incremental replace a multi-dimension array?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a multi-dimensional array A and a multi-dimensional array B. Replace or add the values in array A with the values in array B if the key exists in array B

```
$targetA = array(
        'delete'=>array( 
             'name'=>'a_delete_name',
             'url'=>'a_delete_url'),
        'edit'=>array(
             'name'=>'a_edit_name',
             'url'=>'a_edit_url',
         )
     )
$argumentB = array(
        'delete'=>false,
        'edit'=>array(
            'name'=>'b_edit_name'
         ),
         'forbid'=>array(
            'name'=>'b_forbid_name'
         ),
     )
$result = array(
        'delete'=>false,//replaced
        'edit'=>array(
            'name'=>'b_edit_name'
            'url'=>'a_edit_url'//not replaced!
         ),
         'forbid'=>array(
            'name'=>'b_forbid_name'
         ),
     )
```

Desired is the `$result`

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: But `A:delete:name` doesn't exist in B so way not add it? Can you please define the requirement better? And what have you tried?

Comment: use B to replace A@dWinder

Comment: i have tried by using the RecursiveArrayIterator to find the B`s every terminal path just like B: "delete,edit->name,forbid->name"  then blocked,i have no idea

Comment: A['delete']=B['delete'];A['edit']['name']=B['edit']['name'];A['forbid']['name']=B['forbid']['name']; i tried in this way,but  blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your case:

```
/**
 * Modifies an array to recursively replace the values with another array
 * This function modifies the passed in array, and does not return anything
 * 
 * @param array $startArray Initial array, passed as reference and will be modified
 * @param array $replaceArray Array of values which will replace values in the $startArray
 */
function replaceRecursive(&$startArray, $replaceArray) {
    $keys = array_keys($replaceArray);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($replaceArray[$key])) {
                // If this is another array recurse to replace inner values
            if (is_array($replaceArray[$key])) {

                // Create array key in startArray if it doesn't exist yet
                if (!is_array($startArray[$key])) {
                    $startArray[$key] = array();
                }

                replaceRecursive($startArray[$key], $replaceArray[$key]);
            }
            else {
                // Just replace the key
                $startArray[$key] = $replaceArray[$key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the method like this:

```
$targetA = array(... some values ...);
$argumentB = array(... some values ...);
replaceRecursive($targetA, $argumentB);
var_dump($targetA);
```

Feel free to comment if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
 * get path
 * @param $obj
 * @return array
 */
public function array_path($argumentB){
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($argumentB), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
        if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) {
            for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
                $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
            }
            $paths[] = $p;
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}


/**
 * get value of b
 * @param $path
 * @param $array
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get($path, $array) {
    $temp =& $array;
    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    return $temp;
}

/**
 * set value to A
 * @param $path
 * @param array $array
 * @param null $value
 */
public function set($path, &$array=array(), $value=null) {
    //$path = explode('.', $path); //if needed
    $temp =& $array;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $value;
}

/**
 * main func
 * @param $argumentB
 * @return mixed
 */
public function resetting($argumentB){
    $paths=$this->array_path($argumentB);
    $targetA=include $this->config_file;
    foreach($paths as $v){
        $this->set($v,$config,$this->get($v,$argumentB));
    }
    return $targetA;
}
```

Comment: it is my solution!  emmmmm! seems hard